# Any high-level byte-code editor?

Tags: java, scala, reflection, bytecode

Suppose I have a the following in Scala

```
object Foo {
  var functions: List[String => String] = Nil // can be any type to any type.
  def addFunc(f:String => String) = functions = f :: functions
}
```

At runtime, I am given `Foo` with some functions added. I now want to construct a new .class file implementing something like following in Scala:

```
object MyObject { 
  def process1(s:String) = // call Foo.functions(1)
}
```

I then want to save `MyObject` in bytecode that can be executed later on even when `Foo` is not there.

The above is just an example to show what I want to do . I am given the names `MyObject`, `process1`, and I have to generate an executable file `MyObject.class`. The source of `MyObject` is not needed (it could well have been Java source).

So, at a high level, we need to take memory "snapshot" of `Foo.function(1)`, convert that snapshot into bytecode to store, and generate bytecode of `MyObject` using this.

All the bytecode engineering libraries I found are too low-level, so I was wondering if there is a higher level library that lets me deal with abstract objects such as functions etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at the Tree model of [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)? I've only used the Event model before, but the Tree sounds like just what you're looking for. You'll find an overview in section 1.2.2 of the [ASM user guide](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm-guide.pdf) (a PDF--I don't think there's an HTML version, or I'd link that).

Comment: Asm seems to be the most high-level open-source byte-code editor. It is quite low-level still but will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

I will also recommend [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) framework. There is a paper from AOSD'07 about implementing [common bytecode transformation patterns](http://asm.ow2.org/current/asm-transformations.pdf) with ASM. Sections "Merging Two Classes into One" and "Inline Method" describing bytecode transformations very close to yours.